# Create relation between two PostgreSQL tables

Tags: postgresql

This is structure of two existing tables:

**Table: Location**

```
  -------------------------
  PK varchar | Symbol               
  PK int     | LocationID
  FK int     | Shop 
  -  varchar | Address
```

Information:

```
Composite key of:               Symbol and LocationID
Foreign key to Shop's table:    Shop
```

**Table: Shop**

```
  -------------------------
  PK varchar | Symbol           
  PK int     | ShopID
  timestamp  | SomeDate
```

Information:

```
Composite key of: Symbol and ShopID
```

**This is how i can join both tables:**

```
SELECT * FROM Location As location 
         INNER JOIN Shop As shop
         ON location.Shop = Shop.ShopID AND location.Symbol = Shop.Symbol
```

However in Postgres I need to make relation between those tables. In DbEaver in the ER diagram there is no graphical possibility to draw relationship.

**What is the command to create such relationship?**

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` statements are usually a lot better if you want to show us the structure of your table. Your "format" is highly unusual - a `CREATE TABLE` statement would be much easier to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) you declare a foreign key constraint:

```
alter table location
  add constraint fk_location_shop
  foreign key (shop, symbol) 
  references shop (shopid, symbol);
```

The columns of the foreign key must include all columns of the primary key of the referenced table. That's why you need `foreign key (shop, symbol)`

Comment: can you also tell me when there is 1-1 relatshion how to make such command?